# Uninitialized Constant Breadcrumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following this gist: https://gist.github.com/riyad/1933884/#file-bootstrap_breadcrumbs_builder-rb-L2

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= render_breadcrumbs :builder => ::BootstrapBreadcrumbsBuilder, :separator => "&raquo;" %>
```

I put this in my config/application.rb: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]`

I put the bootstrap_breadcrumbs_builder.rb in my config/lib.

I get this error though: `uninitialized constant BootstrapBreadcrumbsBuilder`

Comment: have u included the breadcrumbsonrails gem?

Comment: @MikeK, yes it's in my app

Comment: Since this needs to be auto loaded why not make it an initializer rather than put it in `autoload_paths`? Also if you would like to use `autoload_paths` it should not be in `config/lib` but just in `lib`  `config.root` will return the base path e.g. `/path/to/your/application` and `lib` will be a sub directory of this. It is essentially the same as `Rails.root` so I think this is your issue (you just placed the file in the wrong spot.) run a console and type `Rails.application.config.root` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @engineersmnky, Great idea, I put it as an initializer and it worked. Will you add that as an answer?

Comment: @Muhambi added. I prefer this as an initializer but for future reference please keep in mind the other key point of what `config.root` actually references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this needs to be auto loaded why not make it an initializer rather than put it in `autoload_paths`? (i.e. `config/initializers/bootstrap_breadcrumbs_builder.rb`)

Also if you would like to use `autoload_paths` it should not be in `config/lib` but just in `lib`. `config.root` will return the base path for the application e.g. `/path/to/your/application` and `lib` would be be a sub directory of this.

It is essentially the same as `Rails.root` so I think this is your issue (you just placed the file in the wrong spot.)

Run a console and type `Rails.application.config.root` and you will see what I mean.